# iOS how to implement share button

Tags: ios, objective-c

im reasking this question i have a uiwebview with a button inside the webview looks like this:

Share Application

now what i need the app to get url and check the first 4 characters = “sha:” if true, run share command, if false, open in webview.

Now by sharing the app i want kind off this

```
NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codingexplorer.com/"];

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: need more detail.. You want to share the App on?

Comment: if the user click share application I want the app to send out the link with small note for example hey check out this new app on App Store...

Comment: it is very simple just create one methods for sharing data and add target and in that call method for share data in selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below code in action method of share button

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
  [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL]
                                    applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController
                                      animated:YES
                                    completion:^{
  // ...
}];
```

Here in string variable put your text and in URL variable assign your share URL.

Answer (score 0):

*I give you a practical example of how I've structured it in my app:*

```
share = [[UIButton alloc] init];
                [share setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_share_ios"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                share.frame = CGRectMake(25, 90, 18, 18);
                [share        addTarget:self
                                 action:@selector(btnShare:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [mainView addSubview:share];





 -(void)btnShare:(id)sender {

    NSArray *objectsToShare;

    NSString* shareText = @"hey check out this new app on App Store";
    NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlExternalPages]];

    objectsToShare = @[shareText, website];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    if ([activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)]) {
        // iOS8+
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [(UIButton *)sender frame];
    }

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in viewController.h i just have :

@interface GR_eventDetail_VC : UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate> {
  UIButton *share;
}

Comment: Did you find it helpful?